# $|a|=m,\,\gcd(m,n)=1 \implies a$ is an $n$'th power

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $a$ belong to a group and $|a|=m$. If $n$ is relatively prime to $m$ show that $a$ can be written as the $n^{th}$ power of some element in the group.

We need to show that if $a\in G$ and  $a^m=e\implies \exists \ b\in G $ such that $b^n=a$ i.e.$b^{nm}=e=({b^m})^n$ i.e. $\exists$ an element of order $mn$ in $G$.

How to show this?

Comment: Your restatement of the problem is not correct. First of all, $b^{mn}=e$ doesn't mean that $b$ has order $mn$. Second, even if you have $(b^n)^m=e=a^m$, this doesn't mean $b^n=a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$ (so $H=\{a^1, a^2, . . . , a^m=e\}$). Consider the map $f: H\rightarrow H$ given by $f(x)=x^n$. Can you show that $f$ is injective? Do you see why the injectivity of $f$ solves your problem?

SUBHINT: Suppose $f$ *weren't* injective. Then $a^{xn}=a^{yn}$ for some distinct $x, y$ in $\{1, . . . , m\}$. Suppose WLOG that $x<y$. Then $a^{(y-x)n}=e$ (why?). If $n$ is coprime to $m$, do you see why this yields a contradiction?

It will be useful to prove the following:

> If $a$ has order $n$, then $a^k=e$ iff $n\vert k$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Euclid's algorithm - If $n$ and $m$ are coprime we can find $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $pn + qm = 1.$ Then, $1=a^{qm} = a^{1-pn}.....$ can you continue from here?

Comment: Nice application of Bezout's theorem!

Comment: Said conceptually: $\,a = a^{\large\,\color{#c00} p\,n} = \left(a^{\large\color{#c00}{\frac{1}n}}\right)^{\large n}$ by $\ \color{#c00}{p\equiv \frac{1}n}\pmod m\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}{pn = 1} - qm,\,$ see my answer. @Qwerty

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Simply write $\ a = \left(a^{\Large\frac{1}n}\right )^n,\,$ valid since $\ \frac{1}n\,$ exists mod $\,m.\,$ More explicitly:

By Bezout $\,\gcd(n,m)= 1\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{n'n\equiv 1}\pmod{\! m}\ $ for some $\ n'\, (\equiv n^{-1}\equiv \frac{1}n)$

therefore we conclude that   $\ (a^{\large \color{#c00}{n'}})^\color{#c00}{\large n} = a^{\color{#c00}{\large 1}}\ $ since from  $\ a^m = 1\ $ it follows that $$ a^{\large\color{#c00} j} = a^{\large\color{#c00} k} \ \ {\rm if}\ \ \color{#c00}{j\equiv k}\pmod m$$

i.e. exponents on $\,a\,$ can be considered mod $\,m.$

**Remark** $\ $ This is a generalization of the well known fact that if $\,n\mid k\,$ then $\, a^{\large k}\,$ is an $n$'th power. Indeed if $\, k = jn\,$ then $\, a^{\large k} = a^{\large jn} = (a^{\large j})^{\large n}.\,$ Above is the special case $\,k= 1\,$ and $\,n\mid 1\pmod{\! m}\,$