# If 3 is not a divisor of the order of a group, then $\forall g \in G$ $\exists h \in G$ s.t $g=h^3$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof, group-isomorphism

[Duplicate 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891398/a-m-gcdm-n-1-implies-a-is-an-nth-power)

[Duplicate 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333882/3-does-not-divide-g-implies-forall-g-in-g-g-h3-for-some-h-in-g)

Here, I attempted an alternative proof for a restricted case (when the operation is commutative)

Let us define a homomorphism $ \phi:G \rightarrow G $
such that, $\phi (x) =x^3 $

The operation being commutative, the function is a homomorphism. Now, $ker ( \phi) =\{e\}$, i.e. the mapping is injective. Since $\phi$ is one to one and a mapping on the set itself (same cardinality) , it is surjective. Hence, we are done here.

Now, for the original question, can we follow the same route with some modification? I like the Bezout's Identity argument, but I want to do it in a bit different fashion.

Comment: Your cardinality argument goes wrong for infinite groups. Multiplication by $3$ is injective on the integers, but not onto.

Comment: @Randall I have assumed it to be a finite group.

Comment: Beware: the map $\phi$ is NOT automatically a homomorphism! It is just a map and bijective if and only if gcd$(|G|,3)=1$.

Comment: @NickyHekster The operation has been assumed commutative. Is this true for the particular case?

Comment: Then you should state abelianess in you post to avoid confusion. But you do not need homomorphism at all, see my answer below.

Comment: @NickyHekster Your proof is pretty nice and straightforward. However, I have seen the usage of Bezout's identity in both of the duplicates (the easiest approach). I just wanted to do it in a bit odd way.

Comment: "The odd way is not always the best way" (Maxime of a famous mathematician) :-)

Comment: @SubhasisBiswas you are right.  I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proposition** Let $G$ be a finite group and $n$ a positive integer. Then the map $f: G \mapsto G$ defined by $f(g)=g^n$ is a bijection if and only if gcd$(|G|,n)=1$.

**Proof** (sketch) Bézout yields $1=k|G|+mn$, for some integers $k, m$. Then $g=g^{k|G|+mn}=g^{mn}$. Hence if $g^n=h^n$, then $g=g^{mn}=h^{mn}=h$. So $f$ is injective and since $G$ is finite it must be bijective. Conversely, assume gcd$(n,|G|)\neq 1$. Then we can find a prime $p$ with $p \mid n$ and $p \mid |G|$. By Cauchy's Theorem there is a non-trivial $g \in G$ with order$(g)=p$. Then $g^n=g^{p \cdot \frac{n}{p}}=1^\frac{n}{p}=1=1^n$. Since $f$ is injective this yields $g=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Simpler: $g=g^{k|G|+mn}=g^{mn}=(g^{m})^{n}$ shows that the map is surjective.